# AllowUsers on sshd_config, forgot to put root

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, root, sshd

I edited `sshd_config` to deny access to SSH to some of my users, just allowing only few users. Here's what I added to the `sshd_config` file:

```
AllowUsers Name1 Name2
```

But I forgot to put in `root` (I though it was not necessary), so now I can't access to SSH with root anymore and with `Name1` and `Name2` I can't edit the `sshd_config` file, because I get *Permission Denied*.

I contacted my host and they told me they can't help me.

Can I get my root access back without physically accessing my dedicated server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

login Name1 via ssh , And `su root` you access by root .